# How to display text and component text on same line

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a div that has some text and then a component that displays some more text:

```
   <div className="text-center">
      Sign-in or <SignUpLink />
    </div>
```

I want it to display the text inline like so:

> Sign in or Create an account

But instead it is displaying like so:

> Sign-in or
>
> Create an account

How can I fix this?

Comment: Whatever elements are returned from the SignUpLink component would need to have a display of ```inline``` or ```inline-block```, or you could make your container div a flexbox.  If it's being pushed to another line the link component is a block element.

Comment: Can we call inline-block with same div className? like <div className="text center inline-block"

Comment: If you're unsure I'd recommend the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) for the CSS display property.

Comment: please post the content of `SignUpLink` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `SignUpLink` a `display: inline` style.

```
const SignUpLink = () => {
  <div style={{ display: 'inline' }}>
    // rest of component
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank You All... It worked.. I used react bootstrap.

Comment: Please mark as answered if it helped you so! @JavaNew

Comment: how  to do that?

Comment: this probably might help you @JavaNew https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers